# How to multiply unknown numbers of arguments each other in a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I'm trying to make a `multiply(#numbers)` function that multiplies everything in the parenthesis and returns the number. How do I multiply the numbers in the parenthesis when I don't know how many numbers there will be?

Here's the code that I got so far:

```
def multiply(*args):
    return *args * *args
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def multiply(*args):
    product = 1
    for a in args:
        product *= a

    return product
```

Basically treat `args` like a list. Cycle through it and multiply. You may want to be careful if you anticipate passing it no parameters. This would output `1` if you just called `multiply()`, but I'm not sure the behavior you're after in that case.

Answer (score 3):

First method:

```
def multiply1(*args):    
    # Multiply elements one by one 
    result = 1
    for x in args: 
         result = result * x  
    return result  
print(multiply1(1,2,4))
```

Second method:

```
import numpy    
# using numpy.prod() to get the multiplications  
def multiply2(*args):      
    return numpy.prod(args)  
print(multiply2(1,2,4))
```

Third method:

```
from functools import reduce
# Python3 program to multiply all values in the 
# list using lambda function and reduce()  
def multiply3(*args):      
    return reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), args)  
print(multiply3(1,2,4))
```

Answer (score 2):

The simpler answers already given may well suit your needs, but the `reduce` command is very powerful at applying a rolling computation sequentially to pairs of numbers in a list.

```
from functools import reduce
def multiply(*args):
    return reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), args)
```

Basically if you perform

```
multiply(1,2,3,4)
```

The `reduce` calculates x*y where x and y are 1 and 2 respectively, then uses the result as x, and y as 3, and continues along the list of numbers multiplying the next one with the result of all previous calculations.

Answer (score 1):

just loop over the args and multiply each item with the  stored result in results variable

```py
def multiply(*args):
    results=1
    for a in args:
        results=results*a
    return results
```

Also, you can do it with sum just set the initial value of results to 0

Answer (score 1):

You're in the right area. `*args` is how you take care of unknown number of arguments. Within your function, `args` will then return a list containing all the arguments.

```
def mult(*args):
    result = 1
    for num in args:
        result *= num
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

**args** is a tuple, so you can use the variable itself. For example:

```
>>> def func(*args):
...     print len(args)
...
>>> func(5, 6, 7)
3
```

To multiply everything as you want:

```
>>> def multiply(*args):
...     return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, args)
...
>>> multiply(1, 2, 3, 4)
24
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others solutions, this solution treats args like a list. However, here an if-statement has been added with an extra return-statement, to make sure that if **no parameters** are passed to the function the output is 0 and not 1.

```
def myFun(*args):

    if len(args) == 0:  
        return(0)       
                    
    product = 1
    for arg in args:
        product *= arg
    return(product)


print(myFun())
print(myFun(8, 5))
print(myFun(8, 5, 2))
print(myFun(8, 5, 2, 3))

# Output: 
0
40
80 
240
```